# Ensuring a generic collection contains objects that derive from two base objects

Tags: c#, type-constraints

I have an interesting problem that I keep circling around, but I never seem to quiet find a solution.

I tend to be a defensive programmer, so I try to write code that prevents problems from happening rather than reacting to problems once they've occurred. To that end, I have the following situation.  Take the following code:

```
public class Base {}
public Interface IBase {}

public class Derived : Base, IBase {}
public class Derived2 : Base, IBase {}
...
public class DerivedN : Base, IBase {}

public class X : Base {}
public class Y : IBase {}
```

I need to pass a list of objects that derive from Base and implement IBase to a collection, and I need to make sure that only objects that have both are added to the list.  Additionally, there can be an arbitrary number of classes that have both, so I cannot use the derived classes as constraints.

If I make the list of type Base, then I could add a Y object.  If I make it of type IBase, then objects of type X can be added (neither of which are permitted).

I could, of course create my own generic collection class that has both types and has constraints for both.  But, I don't want to have to do this for all possible collection types, and it's a lot of effort to duplicate all that functionality (even if you just forward the method calls to a contained class).

I could also create a BaseWithIBase class, which derives from both Base and IBase, and use that as my collection type, but I really don't want to force another abstraction if I don't have to.

I don't want this to be a runtime check, so walking the tree and throwing exceptions is not acceptable.

Can anyone suggest a better approach to this problem?

NOTE: Base and IBase are not related, just pointing out they are both base items of different types.

**EDIT:**

It seems that everyone wants to insist that "you don't need to do that" and that it's "not OOP".  Nothing could be further from the truth.  I was attempting to remove the specific from the question to prevent these kinds of questions and comments, so I will include my real situation.

The code is an implement of a Windows Service framework, based on the .NET Frameworks ServiceProcess.ServiceBase class.  I am adding my own framework on top of this, that is intended to be heavily Dependency Injection based, and highly testable.

The collection must contain objects that derive from both ServiceBase and IService.   IService is my framework extension that is used in my code, and for testing.  It is basically just this:

```
public interface IService 
{
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}
```

In addition, I have a number of other interfaces:

```
public interface IRestartableService
{
    void Restart();
}

public interface IConfigurableService
{
    void Configure();
}
```

etc.. etc.. and a service may look like this:

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase, IService, IConfigurableService {}
```

My code requires IService, Windows requires ServiceBase, thus both are needed because I work with IService, and windows works with ServiceBase.  I only require IService, the other interfaces are optional.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of `Base` and `IBase`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own *wrapper* collection simply:

```
// TODO: Work out which collection interfaces you want to implement
public class BaseList
{
    // Or use List<IBase>, if that's how you'll be using it more often.
    private List<Base> list = new List<Base>();

    public void Add<T>(T item) where T : Base, IBase
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

By using a generic method with both constraints, you can be sure that `Add` can only be called with an appropriate type argument.

You could have two methods to expose the data as `IEnumerable<T>` - one returning `IEnumerable<IBase>` (using `Cast<T>`) and one returning `IEnumerable<Base>`... that would let you use LINQ on *either* type, but not both at the same time of course.

I suspect you may find this awkward elsewhere, however - you may find yourself littering your code with generic methods which you wouldn't typically need. While there may well be a good reason for wanting both the class part and the interface part, it would be worth taking a step back and considering whether they're really both necessary. Is there something extra you could add to the interface so that you could do away with the class constraint, for example?

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned I could do that.. but I don't want to have to do all that work, particularly because I want to use Linq, and IEnumerables, and basically have the ability to do things like .AsReadOnlyList(), etc..  Making all that work a lot of effort.  That means implementing all the collection extension methods as well...

Comment: @MystereMan: What I described didn't sound like any of the alternatives you suggested. Apologies if it's what you had in mind for one of them, but it really wasn't clear. If you're wanting to use a single `List<T>`, how do you expect to get values out of them? I'm afraid that you're probably not going to be able to satisfy your requirements without extra code.

Comment: The part where I said "Of course I could create my own generic collection class" is where I thought I was being pretty unambiguous about it.  I'm not against writing extra code, i'm against writing a metric boatload of extra code in order to recreate all the functionality provided by the various collection classes, extension methods, and interfaces they all support.  This is intended to be a utility item in a framework class, so I can't skimp and only implement what i'm currently using.

Comment: @MystereMan: But my answer *isn't* a generic collection class. It's a non-generic class with generic methods, which isn't the same thing. And you don't have to rewrite all the functionality provided by extension methods - if you're happy to treat it as a sequence of just *one* of the types at a time, you can just expose a view on the sequence, and let LINQ do the rest. But you really can't treat it as a single collection type which is both... it's just not going to work. You'll either need to do something like I've shown, or rethink your design.

Comment: I'm not treating it as both, I'm requiring that they be both.  The reason is that the .NET Framework requires the base class, my code requires the interface.  I can't change the framework (well, not without reverse engineering the ServiceBase class) so I have to pass it objects that derive from ServiceBase, but I need to work with interfaces.  See my edit to my question.

Comment: @MystereMan: My point is that you haven't really told us much about what you want to do with this collection - you've said elsewhere that you need to have a `ServiceBase[]`. Fine - in my scheme, you could do that by calling whatever method exposes `IEnumerable<ServiceBase>`, and then calling `ToArray` on that. You can do similar queries with the interface version - but any time that you need to pass it around as "a collection of items which are both the class and the interface" you'll need the extra collection. I really don't think there's an easier approach here, without changing your design.

Comment: Yes, I realize that implementing IEnumerable alone is fairly powerful by itself.  I have my list of IService, because that's 99.9% of what i'm working with, I simply call _services.Cast<ServiceBase>().ToArray() to pass to ServiceBase.Run().  So this really is a case of objects with split identities, they are treated as ServiceBases by the BCL and IServices by my framework, and containment isn't an option because each service is stand-alone but I have to pass the array to ServiceBase (because it supports service hosting of multiple services in a single host exe)

Comment: @MystereMan: Right. So the class I've shown provides a collection which guarantees that every element has both identities, and you can fetch a view using either identity. So what doesn't that let you do? Note that in this case it sounds like you'd be better off using `List<IBase>` rather than `List<Base>` as I showed it - I'll edit to explain that.

Comment: Also, I guess it's a matter of semantics, but I still consider your "wrapper" class to be a generic collection, because it uses generics in the Add method (which is how the constraints are applied), that's really what I was saying when I said I could create a my own generic collection, not that that it was completely generic..  In any event, what i'm missing is stuff like List.ForEach, and other functionality that isn't Enumerable based.  I suppose it's just my own pet peeve that I dislike any custom collection classes, except when used as property collections.

Comment: @MystereMan: It's not a generic *type*, which is what every other generic collection I've ever seen is. I hope you can see why I didn't think what you were describing is what I described. Anyway, I still think it's the best you're going to get, based on a design idea which basically isn't thoroughly supported by .NET.

Comment: Yes, I am beginning to agree.  As usual, you are the voice of reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer to your question because the design itself is not really fitting OOP as implemented in C#/.NET.

If you absolutely need a collection where each element statically provides two independent interfaces, either a wrapper collection or some wrapper class like `Wrapper<TFirst, TSecond, T> : IBoth<TFirst, TSecond>` would solve your problem.

Example:

```
public interface IBoth<TFirst, TSecond> {
    TFirst AsFirst();
    TSecond AsSecond();
}

public class Wrapper<T, TFirst, TSecond> : IBoth<TFirst, TSecond>
   where T : TFirst, TSecond
{
    private readonly T _value;

    public Wrapper(T value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public TFirst AsFirst() {
        return _value;
    }

    public TSecond AsSecond() {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

However the real question is why do you need that. Not to say that standard OOP model is perfect, but quite often a problem can be solved much easier if original design decisions are reviewed.

Comment: The real code actually has a number of different interfaces and a specific base class (based around Windows Services and ServiceBase).  The idea is to allow mix-in interfaces to provide different functionality, without requiring a leaky single interface, much like how the collection classes themselves already implement a number of different interfaces with different functionality.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I also already mentioned that I could do this, but did not want to introduce another abstraction if I didn't have to.  I realize I may have to, but I'd rather try not to.

Comment: Why make those interfaces mandatory? Also, if the ServiceBase API is mandatory, can you just include these methods into the relevant interfaces.

Comment: ServiceBase is mandatory, because that's the .NET implementation of a Windows Service.  I have to pass a collection of ServiceBase objects to the `ServiceBase.Run()` method.  I cannot pass a different abstraction to the .NET framework.

Comment: Fair enough -- but I do not think you will find a perfect solution to this. In some languages it would be as simple as `Collection<Base&IBase>`, but not in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to completely ignore `ServiceBase` in most of the code and create a `ServiceBaseAdapter` for communication with the code that is not interface friendly. Such adapter can just call your interface methods when its method are called.

Comment: Perhaps i'm misunderstanding you, but if you mean what I think, then that doesn't really work here because of the tight OS integration of ServiceBase, and the way services have to be run by the framework.

Comment: What I mean is basically `ServiceBase.Run(services.Select(s => new ServiceBaseAdapter(s)).ToArray())`.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
List<object> collection = new List<object>();
foreach(var obj in collection.OfType<Base>().OfType<IBase>())
{
// Do what ever you want
}
```